# Getting format for date

Tags: apex, datetime

In a visual force page, I can take a date and do this...

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date, MMMM d,  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.my_date__c}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

I want to be able to do that in Apex code.  So I want a method which takes a date and returns a certain format as a string.

I check the API: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm  and sorry if I am stupid but not so obvious how to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try Datetime.format instead of Date.format. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UPDATE

For the following format

> February 2, 2013

please use:

```
Datetime myDatetime = Datetime.now();
String myDatetimeStr = myDatetime.format('MMMM d,  yyyy');
```

---

Im using the following functions for the timestamp:

```
// This method returns a whole timestamp as a string
public String timeStamp(){
    Datetime dt = Datetime.NOW();
    String day = checkLength(String.valueOf(dt.day()));
    String month = checkLength(String.valueOf(dt.month()));
    String hour = checkLength(String.valueOf(dt.hour()));
    String minute = checkLength(String.valueOf(dt.minute()));
    String second = checkLength(String.valueOf(dt.second()));

    return = String.valueOf(dt.year()) + month + day + '-' + hour + minute + second;
}

// Here i check the length of the day/month/...
// because the month() for example can return 3 for March and i want to have 03
private String checkLength(String val){
    if(String.isNotBlank(val) && val.length() == 1){
        val = '0' + val;
    }
    return val;
}
```

And my output looks like this then: **2013.02.08 08:30:56**

Comment: Thanks suppose you wanted your output to look like February 2, 2013

Comment: @dublintech just updated & simplified my example

Comment: Your `timeStamp()` method seems very inefficient -- how could you refactor it to just use the `Datetime.format()` method and still get the same output?  Post that and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @mast0r I agree with @tomlogic. Your implementation for `timeStamp()` is very inefficient and is a bad example. It would be much more efficient to use the `DateTime.format()` e.g. `DateTime.now().format('yyyyMMdd - HHmmss')`

Answer (score 19):

You are looking for the [Datetime.format()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) method. In your instance, you should be able to use:

```
String formattedDate = relatedTo.my_date__c.format('MMMM d, yyyy');
```

This method utilizes the same format as the [Java SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Specifically, you should read up on the Date & Time Patterns section and review the table there. It will allow you to format the date however you like. The following strings are available for formatting:

[image: Examples of available Strings]

The following are some examples of the strings you can use and what type of results would be returned:

[image: Examples of strings in use]

Answer (score 2):

http://www.interactiveties.com/b_locale_datetime.php

The component that is explained is very good for formatting.You may like to use that with specific locale

Comment: This is a cool article but it doesn't really answer the user's question. He is trying to change the formatting in Apex, not in Visualforce.