# How to assign string to date type in apex code

Tags: apex, date, string

In my code i am getting this error:

> Illegal assignment from String to Date

Kindly anyone explain how to assign a string to date field in List (APEX code).

Here is my code:

```
for (Integer i=1; i<filelines.size(); i++) { 
    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{}; 
    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(','); 
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(); 
    opp.Name = inputvalues[3]; 
    opp.OPP_DateOfBirth__c = inputvalues[4]; 
    opp.StageName = inputvalues[6]; 
    opp.CloseDate = inputvalues[5]'; 
    opptoupload.add(opp); 
}
```

Comment: Have you read the Apex reference materials?

Comment: Check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8246/getting-format-for-date out

Comment: Please put more effort into your question - if you can share with us your string and the way you are assigning it, you will find the community more responsive.

Comment: Please indicate which line is causing the error and some sample data.

Comment: @LavanyaSanathkumar try using this `opp.CloseDate = date.valueof(inputvalues[5]);`.This will change the string value into date Value

Comment: Hi i tried this but i am getting VF error.

Comment: Invalid date: 20-4
Error is in expression '{!ReadFile}' in component <apex:page> in page uploadaccountsall

Comment: can u let me know what value is coming into this (inputvalues[5]).Once try this `opp.CloseDate = date.newInstance(inputvalues[5]);` .This document will help u in converting string to date value http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_date.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_methods_system_date.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: I am getting this error after i have to these.opp.CloseDate = date. newInstance(inputvalues[5]); Error Message:Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: date.newInstance(String)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried [Date.parse()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm)? From the documentation:

> Constructs a Date from a String. The format of the String depends on
> the local date format. The following example works in some locales:
>
> `date mydate = date.parse('12/27/2009');`

Comment: Code:
        for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
        {
            String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
            inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.Name = inputvalues[3];
           opp.OPP_DateOfBirth__c  = inputvalues[4];       
           opp.StageName = inputvalues[6];
          opp.CloseDate = inputvalues[5]';       
            opptoupload.add(opp);
        }

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes i tried date.parse but after this i am VF error.

Comment: @LavanyaSanathkumar I've inserted your code to your question body. Please don't post it here.